# White space occurs with zoom in

Tags: css, reactjs, whitespace

I'm recloning Netflix's Sign In page, but I've noticed that when I zoom in excessively, unexpected white space emerges at the bottom of the background image. This white space becomes more pronounced as I continue to zoom.

Here's the important snippet of the code for your reference:

Auth.tsx

```
const Auth = () => {
     return (  
          <div className="authBg">
          <div className="darkShade">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <div className="signInBox">
              <h1> Log in </h1>
              <Input id="email" label="email"/>
              <Input id="pw" label="password"/>
              <button> Log in </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

Input.tsx

```
const Input = ({id, label}: InputProps) => {
     return ( 
          <div className="inputBox">
               <input id={id}
               placeholder=" "
               >
               </input>
               <label
               htmlFor={id}>
               {label}   
               </label>
          </div>
     );
}
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  align-content: center;
}

.authBg {
  background: url("./assets/default-bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.darkShade {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Could you recommend a standard method to prevent these occurrences of white space during zooming in and out?

Initially, I considered scaling the background image as I zoom by adding a media query shown below, but it doesn't appear to yield optimal results.

```
@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .authBg {
    background-size: 300%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
```

I've also tried using `background-attachment: fixed;` and setting min height  `min-height: 100vh;` instead of setting height.

I'd greatly appreciate your assistance/insight